# Implicit 'this' cannot reference extension methods in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, extension-methods

I have created a custom extension method to make adding constraints to views easier to do in code. Now when I wanted to use it, I couldn't get it to work. I imported my namespace where the extesion resides, and I tried calling it using the implicit `this` (so without specifying it), and it didn't work.

So I had something like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods {

    public static void Constrain(this UIView view, /*parameters with some defaults*/)
    {
        view.AddConstraint( /*the same parameters*/ );
    }
}

public class MyCustomView: UIView
{
    public MyCustomView()
    {
        Constrain(/*parameters*/);
    }
}
```

Which didn't work. Then I added `this.` before the `Constrain` method call, it works, like so:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods {

    public static void Constrain(this UIView view, /*parameters with some defaults*/)
    {
        view.AddConstraint( /*the same parameters*/ );
    }
}

public class MyCustomView: UIView
{
    public MyCustomView()
    {
        this.Constrain(/*parameters*/);
    }
}
```

Is this a flaw in Xamarin's implementation of C# or is this supposed to be this way (if so, why?)?

Comment: This is simply not part of the allowed syntax for calling extension methods. You *must* specify what to call the extension method on/with. I could imagine that part of the rationale for not supporting this would be that if the class itself relies on this method then it shouldn't be an extension method, but obviously I have no idea why they didn't chose to implement support for this. This is not supported outside of Xamarin either so this is not just some lapse in the Xamarin implementation, it's just not part of legal and allowed C# syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply not part of the allowed syntax.

The syntax for invoking extension methods is specified in the [C# Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), section 7.6.5.2 - Extension Method Invocations, and is shown as:

> **7.6.5.2 Extension Method Invocations**
> In a method invocation (§7.5.5.1) of one of the forms
>
> ```
> expr . identifier ( )
> expr . identifier ( args )
> expr . identifier < typeargs > ( )
> expr . identifier < typeargs > ( args )
> ```
>
> if the normal processing of the invocation finds no applicable methods, an attempt is made to process the construct as an extension method invocation. If expr or any of the args has compile-time type dynamic, extension methods will not apply.

You can see that the legal forms involve `expr.`, something which isn't present when you call methods declared in the same type.

Comment: Okay, do you have a suggested rationale why this might be the case? I just want to understand it.

Comment: I can only guess, but see the comment I made on your question for one such guess.